# CSS in Bootstrap 4 ''Mask''

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

There is the use of "Mask" in Bootstrap 4 or 5. How can I do this in CSS? Adding background color and z-index to an image does not accept it.

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/content-styles/masks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDB bootstrap is non-official version of bootstrap that contain components, templates, animations and more. It's not free 100% .

The idea of mask is very simple, here is how to do it without bootstrap :

```css
.bg-image{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width:300px;
}

.bg-image .mask{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    color:#fff;
}

.bg-image .mask .text{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex!important;
    align-items: center!important;
    justify-content: center!important;
}

.bg-image .mask .text p{
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-image">
  <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/city/053.jpg" style="width:300px" />
  <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)">
    <div class="text">
      <p>Hello There!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, finally. Thank u so much.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bootstrap-V5 so there is already **predefined** classes for **positions** like **absolute** & **relative**. So write classes into div and draw mask card as you want without write single line of css code.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container py-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4">
    
      <div class="position-relative">
        <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/bootstrap-icons.png" class="w-100">
        <div class="position-absolute top-0 left-0 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center w-100 h-100 text-white fs-5" style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);">
          Hello Mask
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the boostrap in order for it to work

Install package:

```
npm install bootstrap@3
```

Add the following codes in script

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check out the Developer Tools to see in detail, how they solved this issue. They are using an image-container which contains the image and the mask. The mask has an absolute position and therefore lays over the image. I simplified the code for you:

```
<div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/city/053.jpg">
      <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-container {
position: relative;
}

.mask {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```